# Is it possible to apply get_user_pages() over a mmap address?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

as the title says: Is it possible to apply get_user_pages to a virtual address obtained by a mmap?
My system is an embedded System composed by a SoC running a Linux distribution ( kernel version 4.6) in combination with an FPGA.
I have a custom module that uses mmap() to return a user pointer to a large chunk of contiguous memory, we will call it MemDriver.  I also have a driver that needs to get the phisical address starting from this virtual user-space address, in order to configure a small DMA that I have developed. Something like this, not in strict C code:

```
int mem_fd = open("/dev/MemDriver");
void* buffer = mmap( mem_fd);
int dma_fd = open("/dev/CustomDevice");
read(dma_fd, buffer, 100);
```

I do not want to use copy_to_user() since I would like to go as fast as possible. Is there any reason on why get_user_pages() on this buffer should return 0 pages?

Comment: So just to be clear you are saying that you tried `get_user_pages()` and it returns 0?

Comment: As an aside (probably not the cause of your problem), for 5.6 kernel onwards you should replace `get_user_pages()` with `pin_user_pages()` for pinning pages for DMA. (Personally, I have only needed to use the "fast" variants, but I have never used them on mmaped device memory.)

Comment: Are you mapping device memory to userspace with something like `remap_pfn_range()`? In that case the `vma` for that mapping will be marked as `VM_PFNMAP` and `VM_IO`. VMAs with these flags are treated in a special way in a variety of situations, so I wouldn't be surprised if they are treated differently by `get_user_pages()` too. In fact, taking a quick glance at the kernel code it seems like `get_user_pages()` should fail with `-EFAULT` if the VMA is marked with `VM_PFNMAP` or `VM_IO` ([code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.6.7/source/mm/gup.c#L422)).